# Gradient of $(x,y) \mapsto y^\top A(x) y$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Given a differentiable $A: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$, let $f: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}$ be a scalar field defined by $$f(x,y) := y^\top A(x) y$$  Can the gradient $\nabla_x f$ be written in closed-form as a function of $A(x)$, $x$ and $y$?

I tried to write the quadratic form as a sum $$\sum_i^m y_i \sum_j^m a_{ij}(x)y_j$$ Differentiation leads straight forward to the sum of vectors $\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x}$ instead of coefficients $a_{ij}(x)$, but I could not identify any structure.

Comment: What have you tried? what happens for $n=m=1$?

Comment: I tried to write the quadratic form as a sum $\sum_i^m y_i \sum_j^m a_{ij}(x) y_j$. Differentiation leads straight forward to the sum of vectors $\frac{\partial a_{ij}}{\partial x}$ instead of coefficients $a_{ij}(x)$, but I could not identify any structure. For $n=m=1$ you have no vector matrix multiplication, which is then solved straigt forward.

Comment: A quadratic form in $y$, right?

Comment: @Trb2 Only if $A$ does **not** depend on $x$. A quadratic form is not vector-transpose-times-matrix-times-vector but rather a polynomial in which every monomial is degree-2.

Comment: I understand, thank you. I edited it. Do you have some idea on which way to proceed to obtain a solution?

Comment: Can you compute the partial derivative $\partial_{x_1} f$? Do not use sums

Comment: You cannot avoid using partial derivatives of $a_ij(x)$, unless $A(x)$ assumes a very special structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \nabla_{\bf x} f ({\bf x}, {\bf y}) = \begin{bmatrix} {\bf y}^\top \left( \partial_{x_1} {\bf A} ({\bf x}) \right) {\bf y} \\  \vdots \\ {\bf y}^\top \left( \partial_{x_n} {\bf A} ({\bf x}) \right) {\bf y} \end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: true, thank you!